# What to do with the intercept output from regression analsyis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, regression

In ArcGIS I use global Ordinary Least Squares Regression (OLS) models and Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR) models to analyze the relationships between independent variables and my dependent variable.

What ArcGIS also includes in the results is an intercept term. I know basically the meaning of the intercept, but what I am unsure is - has the intercept to be interpreted and if yes, how exactly?

For GWR I get for each local unit an intercept - is it necessary/important/good to see the local variations of the intercept?